# How to Highlight Second Highest Values in Google Sheets Using Conditional Formatting?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, max, conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets, I would like to highlight the 2nd highest value in a column of a table.

I am making a table in Google Sheets and want to highlight all 2nd highest values using conditional formatting.

[Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvvjd.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use `large()`, like this:

```
=C5 = large(C$5:C, 2)
```

In the event there are two or more copies of the highest or second highest value, all of those copies will get highlighted.

See [large()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094008).

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that OP wants to highlight cells equal to the second highest unique value, i.e.

```
=C5=large(unique(C$5:C),2)
```